# Setting open and close times with quantmod

Tags: r, quantmod

I'm working on futures contracts in R. The futures market opens at 6pm EST and ends the next day at 5pm EST. I'm dealing with data at the hour level. When I use quantmod it assumes the Open is at 12:00am and Close is at 11:59pm. Is there a way to change the Open and Close time or is there a better way to solve the problem?

Comment: Can you let us know what exactly you are trying to do? are you calculating daily OHLC info from higher frequency i.e hourly data?

Comment: I am calculating sd, mean, trends, and plotting some of the built in features such as MACD and BBands. Often the hourly scale is too granular so I need to move up to daily or monthly scale (to.daily, to.monthly). That is when the Open and Close times gets out of sync.

Answer (score 1):

The usual trick here is to set a timezone so that midnight matches the day end. The problem with EST is the summertime/wintertime switch, but because your market is 23hrs, not 24hrs, you do not need to deal with it (as opposed to FX markets).

If you are trying to process one day of data at a time, in R, I use the example code below. It is a modification of `rollapply.right`. My script, and `data`, are in the UTC timezone. (`data` might be tick data, or hourly data, or anything imbetween).

The basic idea is to take a copy of the data, move that copy to a different timezone, run `endpoints` on it, then use the result of `endpoints` on your original data. The `7*3600' adjustment moves 5pm forward to midnight.

```
rollapply_chunks.FX.xts=function(data,width,FUN,...,on="days",k=1){
data <- try.xts(data)

x2 <- data
index(x2) <- index(x2)+(7*3600)
indexTZ(x2) <- 'America/New_York'

ep <- endpoints(x2,on=on,k=k)    #The end point of each calendar day (when on="days").
    #Each entry points to the final bar of the day. ep[1]==0.

if(length(ep)<2){
    stop("Cannot divide data up")
}else if(length(ep)==2){  #Can only fit one chunk in.
    sp <- 1;ep <- ep[-1]
}else{
    sp <- ep[1:(length(ep)-width)]+1
    ep <- ep[(width+1):length(ep)]
}

xx <- lapply(1:length(ep), function(ix) FUN(.subset_xts(data,sp[ix]:ep[ix]),...) )
xx <- do.call(rbind,xx)   #Join them up as one big matrix/data.frame.

tt <- index(data)[ep]  #Implicit align="right". Use sp for align="left"
res <- xts(xx, tt)
return (res)
}
```